# pgAdmin 4 - preferences settings not applied

Tags: windows-10, settings, pgadmin-4

I'm using pgAdmin 4 (v. 6.12) on Windows 10.

Since (I believe) version 6.10 I've noticed that autocomplete always shows up. I tried to change preferences settings to only show it on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>:

[image: Auto completion settings]

But it made no difference - autocomplete is always shown.

Then I've noticed, that some other settings are not respected, for example *insert bracket pairs*:
[image]

This is how editor looks just after typing opening bracket:
[image]

This is very annoying. I've completely removed previous installation of pgAdmin: uninstalled it, deleted all files and folders with `pgAdmin` in name and did the same in Windows registry. But new installation behaves the same.

New installation was made only for my user account, not for `Anyone who uses this computer` option.

Comment: I just upgraded to pgAdmin4 6.12 on ubuntu and there also, the autocomplete pops up every quarter-second.  I have it turned completely off and it won't get out of the way, making the tool unusable.  Surely we are not the only ones with this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you, I was also unable to turn off autocomplete-on-type after installing 6.12.

When using the web client, I was able to log out and log back in to solve it.

UPDATE from comments: using the Windows application, Adam was able to clean session data from the registry, open the editor window, change settings, close editor window, change settings… And it started to work again.

More details...

It happened to me in Ubuntu when I first upgraded to 6.12 and restarted the server, while the client was connected.  The web client appears to have held on to a session that at first seemed to work.  Once I logged out and log back in, my autocomplete-on-type OFF setting was respected again.

I agree that this bug is completely frustrating.  I'm not sure why anyone would want the autocomplete-on-type setting enabled, pgadmin4 is unusable with it on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, please, explain what do you mean by _logged out of the web client_? I use standalone client program (`pgAdmin4.exe`) and there is a remote server. I can _Disconnect from server_, _Clear Saved Password_ or _Reset Master Password_ - none of which makes any difference, there is no _logout_ option. Or how else can I clear such a held session? There is possibility that I have dropped a test database while I was connected to it, so your suggestion seems to be true.

Comment: Oh right, I have a different environment than you.  With the web client you have to log in to a pgadmin4 web page before you connect to any database.  That's the log in/out I was referring to.  It does make me feel like there must be some kind of session data in Windows, perhaps in the registry... I'll see if I can find that...

Comment: Here is where pgadmin4 data is stored in the registry, maybe there is something there you can clear out to get it working?  I'd make sure to keep a copy before removing - probably best to just rename the folder instead of removing settings.  `%CommonProgramFiles%\pgadmin\config_system.py`

Comment: I've found sessions saved in `%APPDATA%\pgadmin\sessions` and deleted them but it did not help :(

Comment: Ah bummer.  Sorry.  How can we solve this, it's so annoying... Maybe time to submit an official bug: https://www.pgadmin.org/support/issues/

Comment: I did the following several times: opened editor window, changed settings, closed editor window, changed settings… And it started to work again! Maybe deletion of sessions actually helped.